# Как убрать экранирование символов из текста?

Tags: javascript

Как можно убрать экранирование с помощью regexp (или любого другого способа):

```js
const str = 'some \\n text \\n 1';

console.log(str);
```

То-есть чтобы вместо

```
some \n text \n 1
```

Выводилось

```
some 
text 
1
```

Comment: а в двойные кавычки обернуть?

Comment: или шаблонные строки использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
const str = 'some \\n text \\n 1';

console.log(str.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'));
```